# I want to create a push rejection in Firebase Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I don't want to be pushed, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
switch_push.isChecked = sysPref.pushEnabled

    switch_push.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            sysPref.pushEnabled = isChecked
    }
```

First, I made a switch so that I can reject push and it's being saved well as shared preferences.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.from)
    if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: ${remoteMessage.notification?.body}")
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.notification)
    }
}
```

But, if limit sending a push to the boolean value here, the push will still be sent.

What can I do to limit sending push?

Comment: Hi Reaf, I'm confused what you are trying to achieve

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry, I didn't get it straight on exactly what I wanted to do.
I delivered the push of the app to users through firebase, and I want to add a means to reject it.
I'm asking because I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand the question or not. When `onMessageReceived` , you will just need to call `SharedPreference` and update the value.

Comment: Well, I've tried  'isChecked' for 'SharedPreference', and it's not working, did I do something wrong?

Comment: But where do you update changes inside `onMessageReceived`?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your meaning, can you tell me what you mean by update changes inside? sorry

Comment: You don't want to display notification if the `sysPref.pushEnabled` is `false` ?

Comment: `D/check: check false`

Of course, I checked the log of pushEnabled. Could there be a problem with this code in another package?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.